# jQuery Hotkeys Mysql Insert Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I would like to know how i can make a script that when you press (for example) Numpad 9
There will be a query excecuted. Like insert into chat

Could somebody explain me how it works?

Answer (score 1):

[Mousetrap.js](http://craig.is/killing/mice) is super easy to use and extremely light-weight:

```
Mousetrap.bind('9', function() { 
    window.alert("you pressed the 9 key");
});
```

Comment: @user3625987 Use AJAX to do that inside your function. Please click the checkmark by my answer since I answered your question. Feel free to ask another question if you need help with your AJAX. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks now i got a question, if i minimise my browser i will still need to press 9 but it doesn't enter in my query

Comment: @user3625987 thanks. your browser will need to be in focus in order for that to work. if your browser is minimized mousetrap won't work.

Comment: How can i make it work? does it work if i make a program with a frame in visuals basic?

Comment: @user3625987 if you want to create a hotkey for the operating system you won't be able to use anything from the browser to do it, except maybe an applett. Just use VB and forget about your browser/frame.

Comment: How can i store it in a database with visual basic so that i can see it on my website?

Comment: @user3625987 if you have another question, ask another question, don't post it in the comments. I will not be responding to this thread anymore.